# how to set(assign) dropdownlist selected value & radiobutton selected value in jquery from a json data

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblGender" runat="server" RepeatDirection="horizontal" Height="30px" Width="130px">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="M">Male</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="F">Female</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>    

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="100px"  >
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Based on a selected id (Webservice returns the details of the employee and i need to show it in the form) Id, Code , Name is working good

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "EMService.asmx/GetEmployeeById",
      data: "{ 'Id':'" + id + "' }",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
           var obj = data.d;
           $("#<%=txtId.ClientID%>").val(obj.Id);
           $("#<%=txtCode.ClientID%>").val(obj.Code);
           $("#<%=txtName.ClientID%>").val(obj.Name);
           $("#<%=rblGender.ClientID%>").valueOf(obj.Gender);
           $("#<%=ddlDepartment.ClientID%>").value(obj(Department.Id));
 },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            })
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: BTW you have missed the closing `}` of your ajax success function.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a type while posting but you have missed the `}` closing brace of ajax success.

try to change this:

```
$("#<%=rblGender.ClientID%>").valueOf(obj.Gender);
$("#<%=ddlDepartment.ClientID%>").value(obj(Department.Id));
```

to this:

```
$("#<%=rblGender.ClientID%>").val(obj.Gender);
$("#<%=ddlDepartment.ClientID%>").val(obj.Department.Id);
```

you have used `valueOf` and `.value(obj(Department.Id)`, instead of use just `.val()` and this `.value(obj(Department.Id));` should be `.value(obj.Department.Id);`

Comment: doesn't support "value"

Comment: in the jQuery we have to use `.val()` or if you want to use `.value` then your syntax has to be like this : `$("#<%=rblGender.ClientID%>")[0].value=obj.Gender;`

Comment: btw if you could post your json data to have a look at it, then we can suggest you a better answer.